# how to make alert box size fit the width of the modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

as you can see the warning alert box doesn't correctly match the size of the modal. how can i make it fit its size ?

[image]

and here is the code

```
                            <div id="deleteCurso" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar aluno</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Está prestes a eliminar um curso. Isto irá causar a destruição de todos os triénios, alunos, PAP's e vídeos relacionados ao mesmo. Esta ação é irreversível. Tem a certeza que pretende realizar esta ação?
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_btn" data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Eliminar Curso</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please, post full page with html js and css , so we can test it

Comment: The code you posted does work: http://www.codeply.com/go/bAlC7sc2KF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the class of modal with class="modal modal-lg"

```
<div id="deleteCurso" class="modal fade modal-lg" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

`.alert {display:inline-block;}` will work but it will make all your alerts 100%, so better to add a class and then apply the above styling.